# Cursor positioning in SMS editor

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, keyboard

I bought an Android phone (Philips w632) and I'm unhappy with the text editor used when I SMS because when I want to edit a letter in the middle of a word I need to keep tapping the letter until the cursor gets there. When I tap and hold on, a magnifying glass appears and this shows clearly where the cursor is and it appears as if I can change its position, but the moment I let go the whole word gets highlighted with two tabs on either side.

When I'm typing something in the browser however an orange tab appears under the cursor and I can move this which in turn moves the cursor to the correct position.

I did download Swype with the hopes of changing this situation but unfortunately it has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure as I haven't seen a Philips phone, but it sounds like Philips have put in their own SMS app which doesn't use the standard text entry field. The little tab to help you position the cursor accurately is part of that, not part of the keyboard.

If this is the case, then using a third-party SMS application instead will make it easier to use. There are many on Google Play, so just try one out and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out, but I must say that the keyboard does look a lot like the standard android keyboard. But I will give it a try

Comment: The keyboard is completely irrelevant. What matters is the `TextView`: the box within the app layout, where the text appears.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)? Because I think this is a feature that was added in this version of Android. I know I got this when I upgraded my HTC Desire from Android 2.2 to 2.3. You can see some images below showing this feature in action. *Click the images for high-res.*

[image: lowres]
[image: lowres]
[image: lowres]
[image: lowres]
[image: lowres]

The first four images show this feature in my SMS messaging app, and the last one shows the same feature in my browser. I use the stock apps for SMS and web browsing that came with the phone. But like I said, I didn't have this until I upgraded to Android 2.3.

Now from what I understand this is probably what you get when you try to do the same on your phone.

[image: lowres]

Something like that? And maybe a magnifying window?

You need to make sure you have Android 2.3 (or higher) also known as Gingerbread. If you do have Android 2.3 (at least) then it probably has to do with your SMS messaging app. In that case you need to try a different SMS app.

Here are some SMS messaging apps you can try out.

- [chomp SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms)
- [Handcent SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms)
- [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms)